# ArcMap "Polyline to Raster" output is empty greyscale raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, spatial-analyst, rasterization

I have a polyline shapefile of streams that I am attempting to convert to a raster using the "Polyline to Raster" conversion tool. However, rather than outputting a raster with distinct stream pixels, my output is a seemingly empty raster with a greyscale value scale of 0 to 255. My methodology is as follows:

1) I have created a field within "streams" called "rastervalue"
2) I assigned values of "1" to each stream feature in hope that all stream 
pixels within my output raster are represented by this value.
3) I ran "Polyline to Raster" using the following script:

```
    arcpy.PolylineToRaster_conversion(Streams,"rastervalue")
```

I have attempted this with varying cell sizes, and my results seem to be the same. How can I generate the desired output?

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the symbology of your raster? If the cell values are 1 for streams, and 0 or NoData for the rest, the default display with greyscale 0-255 may appear uniform. Maybe you could also try setting the value to 255 and check out the results.

Comment: @FSimardGIS I have played around with it. I tried to display the results categorically, but it seems like there aren't any values to add.

Comment: What is the field type of your values?

Comment: My "rastervalue" field is a short integer.

Comment: You do not appear to have specified an output dataset. Which raster format do you want to output?

Comment: It seems that ArcMap is assigning a default output with the script that I have, which I am okay with. I am fine with the default ESRI GRID format as well. I have tried assigning a specific output, but I seem to get the same empty result. I will add that when I run the tool through the toolbox GUI, I get the desired results.  However, even when I "copy as a python snippit" those results from the results window and try to run them through the python window, my output seems to be empty.

Comment: Set up environment extent and cell size .

Comment: I have my extents set up to match the extent of a DEM around which I am working. I have tried various cell sizes as well, and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `Cellsize` input. When I tested the tool the default was quite large. Reduce the `Cellsize` value to something that suits your data. Here I have lines that are several hundred feet in length. I made my `Cellsize` 100 to create a rough raster representation of my lines.

[image]

`arcpy.PolylineToRaster_conversion(Streams,"rastervalue", cellsize = 100)`

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, I have set various cell sizes. I have tried large and small values, and the default value that the toolbox UI suggests. I still get the same result...

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm a skimmer. What's the Linear Unit of your input polyline feature class? (Properties -> Source or XY Coordinate System)

Comment: No worries :) The linear units are US Feet.

Comment: Actually, I think you were correct after all! The UI *shows* a default value in feet, but it looks like it actually converts it to decimal degrees?? (I'm not sure if this is a default or if it is because my dataframe is set to decimal degrees). 

So, the values that I thought were small, were actually not small at all. Once I choose an appropriate cell size in decimal degrees, I get my desired results. Thank you for getting me to look at this some more.

Comment: Being a skimmer pays off once again!